# ScrollView collide with UItableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview

My `UIScrollView` inside a nested `UITableView`, in which `UITableView` has a left row pop-up menu of gestures, and now the two views of the gesture conflict. Now the question is: how to solve this problem without changing the `UITableView` ?

PS: I have been set `UIScrollView` `ScrollEnabled=false`

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Share your view hierarchy.

Comment: @BharatModi  http://i.stack.imgur.com/nAXId.png
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfavn.png

Comment: Not this one, Show your document outline.

Comment: @BharatModi http://i.stack.imgur.com/uHkVt.png do you meanthis one?

Comment: Yes, but there is not tableView in your hierarchy.

Comment: @BharatModi Here it is, my tableView is loaded into a class by inheriting a class of SDK.

Comment: Your question is not clear, if your problem is conflict between two gesture then you can set either tag to your gesture or check the View which is sending the gesture event.

Comment: @BharatModi yes,conflict between scrollView and tableView,I think your answer is right,then what should i do specifically?

Comment: @BharatModi Thank you, I saw the hope of solving the problem. The last question is which place should I write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is different but as you agree that your main problem is conflict between the gestures, that means you are not able to differentiate between gesture of two views,

To solved there are two ways, you need to receive gesture based on condition in gestureRecognizer delegate method, you can either check the class which received the gesture or by checking class or by tag

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
   shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if([touch.view class] == [UITableView class]){
    return NO;
    } else if (touch.view.tag == 100) {
    return NO;
    } else if ([NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellContentView"]) {
    return NO;
} 

    return YES;
}
```

What this delegate would do is, it will call the gesture handler method only for the view which you want to handle gesture and also you can differentiate between the gesture recogniser.

Comment: Thank you, I saw the hope of solving the problem. The last question is which place should I write the code?

Comment: In the class, in which you have added the gestured for your views.